# C++ or java openid relayer. How to use openid for login in a desktop app, and security considerations?

Tags: java, c++, openid

I understand that openid is generally used for browser-based application. However, I am building a java desktop application. I would like to use openid. How is it possible. One way that it could be done would be to integrate a java web browser such as http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp and capture the return url. But that seems to me like the hardest solution. Is there a library that can help me do that.

My goal is to use the return url from the openid provider, say google, as a secret key to encrypt local data. The returned url contains a unique access/confirmation key.

What are the security considerations in doing this?

Comment: *(not an answer to your question)*...  One consideration is that if you rely on one OpenID provider per user, it is all too easy to get your user locked out of your app.  The first thing I did when I created my SO account was to register a second OpenID provider "just in case".  The Web is full of OpenID horror stories.  So, just like SO does, allowing (and even suggesting to) your users to associate more than one OpenID with their account may be something to keep in mind...

Comment: Yeah, I have encountered that with web-based site I used. I usually require they use Google, or twitter. And thats it.

Comment: Sure but who doesn't have a twitter or google account? Seems a rather small group really (take me for example: Never used twitter or facebook, so I'm already in the minority, but not even having a google account? Now that's getting unlikely ;) ) Interesting question, I'm hoping for good answers!

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following libraries look like they will probably do what you need:

- http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/
- http://code.google.com/p/joid/

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. Both libraries seem to be used in Web applications. How would one use them in a desktop application (with no browser)? The whole OpenID concept of redirecting the the provider and back seems to be impossible without a browser. Or is there a way?